# Formatting Float value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, floating-point, format

I am trying to create an array list like so

```
val list: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
        list.add(Entry(0F, 110F))
```

I have a string that some like **80/110**. I need to get the **110** convert the string to float and append with F for the above entry. array How can I achieve that in Kotlin?

Comment: So, from an `Entry` object with values 20 and 110 you need to obtain a string in the format `20F/110F`, correct?

Comment: The F is just syntax for your literal number in the code. It's not something you have to append to your string. You can split your string, get the relevant part that's the number you want, and convert it to a Float with `toFloat()`. For example, `"80/100".split("/")[1].toFloat()`. Or `with (theString.split("/").map(String::toFloat)) { Entry(first, second) }`

Comment: Forget the `F` for now; that's only important for numeric literals, and you have a string.  I think what you need to do is split the string at the `/` into two strings, convert each of those into a number, and then create an `Entry` from them.